# Query select all values of specific month

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-dates

A have a table where Column A has dates. I want to get all values of a specific month

I have the following query for May for example

```
=query(Database!A1:AD,"Select A,E,F,U,V,W,X,AB,AC where Month(A) = 5",1)
```

but it does not work. Where I am wrong?
Query

```
=query(Database!A1:AD,"Select A,E,F,U,V,W,X,AB,AC where A > date '2019-05-01' and A < date '2019-05-31'",1)
```

works fine but I have a separate drop-down list with the months' number 01 02 03 .... and I want the query to change when I change the month number. But even when I put the month number directly into query it shows nothing. No any mistake - just no rows with values, only header

Comment: can you share a copy of your sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- months in **`QUERY`** starts from 0 so you need to fix it with **`+1`**

  ```
  =QUERY(Database!A1:AD, "select A,E,F,U,V,W,X,AB,AC where month(A)+1 = 5", 1)
  ```

Comment: Just found out that! Thanks. Now how can I change 5 to a link to the specific cell with a drop-down list?
when I try
=query(Database!A1:AD,"Select A,U,V,W,X,AB,AC where E = '"&B1&"' AND Month(A)+1 = '"&D1&"'",1)
it does not work

Comment: Here I created a copy of the sheet 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1RFkFccPulPSRoOoYeu8h8rK0VwxTv685LXznAohAiLo/edit#gid=498193188

Comment: like this: `=query(Database!A1:AD,"Select A,U,V,W,X,AB,AC where E = '"&B1&"' AND Month(A)+1 = "&D1,1)`

Comment: thanks, now works fine