# Using Query & Import Range function to import data range with a date filter

Tags: google-sheets-query, google-sheets-dates, importrange, integration

I have been able to use the the Query and Import Range function perfectly.

=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13eoPsqGik4ZWFGPURrC9RYdlOuxdbCbQWXzWA9LC1L4/edit#gid=0", "Capital One Checking!A5:F100"),"Select sum(Col6) where Col4 contains 'Fast Food'")

Where I am importing the data from another sheet and selecting the sum of a column 6 ($ spent on specific category Fast Food) based on the criteria from another column which is 'Fast Food' from column 4.
However, I am trying to add another filtered criteria which is for a specific month. How do I add another filtered criteria where it only takes data from a specific month without changing the former applications? I have the date in column 1.

I apologize in advance if  I am not properly formatting the formula correctly by using "code", "bold" or "italic"

Comment: Hi, welcome to WebApps. Would you give a brief summary of your research and any attempts that you made to solve this yourself. Would you also explain how you establish the "specific month"  - for example you might have a dropdown showing month names, or you specify the start (and/or) end dates of a month in a separate cell, etc.

Comment: Related: [QUERY function with date range not working and shows wrong results](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/162770/196152)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Query select all values of specific month](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/129976/query-select-all-values-of-specific-month)

Comment: Unfortunately no. When I add month(A) to the formula I receive an error that states that there is NO_COLUMN: A even though the dates are on column A.
@Tedinoz

Comment: I have used different formats for the Month formula but whenever I add it to the formula above I receive an error. I was trying to do the month of August which I put Month(A)=7 however, the error still says there is NO_COLUMN: A.
Column A begins with a "header" for the dates (which is titled date) and the rest are dates that I would like included in the query formula.

Comment: Below is the error formula I am referring to

=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13eoPsqGik4ZWFGPURrC9RYdlOuxdbCbQWXzWA9LC1L4/edit#gid=0", "Capital One Checking!A5:F100"),"Select sum(Col6) where Col4 contains 'Fast Food' and month(A)=7")

I have also tried month(A)+1=7

Comment: I have researched many sites like this to get the working formula in the first post. I am just having a hard time adding the month without changing the original
@Tedinoz

Comment: "When I add month(A) to the formula I receive an error that states that there is NO_COLUMN: A". In referenced Q&A, the `data` parameter is a simple range, so the `query` parameter references column letters (such as A, C, E, etc). But `IMPORTRANGE` generates an array so the equivalent `query` parameter references Column indexes within the array (such as Col1, Col3, Col5, etc). So if the data is in the first column, then you adapt the Q&A to your circumstances - instead of using `month(A)`, you would use something like: `month(Col1)`.